# Palindromic String in C

Tags: c, palindrome

I am trying to solve this Palindromic String problem in C by using the `strlen()` & `strcmp()` string functions. My idea is to copy the string to another new string and, then, compare the both string.

For copying I used a for loop.

Here I think the problem is. There are in most cases 2-3 extra character in my copied string. I am scratching my hear for a while. This should be an easy problem, but as I am new to problem solving, it's taking a lot of time.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>

    int main()
    {
        char my_string1[100], my_string2[100];

        int i=0, c;
        int j;

        scanf("%s",&my_string1);

        c= strlen(my_string1);
        j=c;

        for( i=0; i<c; i++){
                j=j-1;
                my_string2[i]=my_string1[j];
        }

        printf("\n\nString1:  ");
        puts(my_string1);
        printf("String1's length:  ");
        printf("%d\n\n",c);
        printf("String12:  ");
        puts(my_string2);
        printf("String2's length:  ");
        printf("%d\n",strlen(my_string2));

        if(strcmp(my_string1,my_string2)==0)
        {
            printf("\n\nYES");
        }
        else
            printf("\n\nNO");

    }
```

**Sample Output**

```
aba


String1:  aba
String1's length:  3

String12:  abaO
String2's length:  5


NO
```

```
String1:  abcdse
String1's length:  6

String12:  esdcba
String2's length:  6


NO
```

Comment: add a 0 to terminate the 2nd string

Comment: Each C string needs to be NUL-terminated. You do not copy the NUL, so `strlen` finds random garbage at the end. `my_string2[c] = 0` should do it.

Comment: Tommylee2k said it, you're most likely missing the 0 at the end of the string. That's how C knows it is the end of the string. I think you should `string[n] = 0` where `n = strlen(string)`. But as a suggestion, you don't need to copy anything, try comparing the characters of a single string: like comparing `string[j]` and `string[n - j - 1]`.

Comment: Another solution you could try is to solve it without creating a new char array. Just calculate `j` in the for loop and compare the char in `j` with the char in `i` in the same original array.

Comment: If you add `my_string2[i] = '\0';` just after the for-loop then ....

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


int main()
{
    char my_string1[100];

    int i=0, c;

    scanf("%s",my_string1);

    c= strlen(my_string1);

    bool equal = true;
    for( i=0; i<c/2; i++) {  // compare first half and the second half of the string
        if( my_string1[i] != my_string1[c-i-1] ) {
             equal = false;
             break;
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nString1:  ");
    puts(my_string1);
    printf("String1's length:  ");
    printf("%d\n\n",c);

    if( equal ) {
        printf("\n\nYES");
    } else {
        printf("\n\nNO");
    }
}
```